# Set java_opts for baserecalibrator snakemake wrapper

Tags: java, conda, wrapper, snakemake

I am running a snakemake pipeline with some conda wrappers and I'm trying to allocate some more memory to a rule since it's taking ages. I tried to allocate more memory and threads through the java opts, but the rule fails. I can't provide an error message. I'm running on a cluster and the log says I should look in the log files of the involved rules. This log file is empty though.

This is my code for the rule:

```
rule recalibrate_base_qualities:
    (unchanged)
    params:
        (unchanged)
        java_opts="-Xmx4G -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8", # also tried just: java_opts="-Xmx4G",
    threads: 8
    resources:
        mem_mb=32768,
        time="12:00:00", # just for cluster scheduling
    wrapper:
        "0.74.0/bio/gatk/baserecalibrator"
```

Can anyone help me spot the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without setting `java_opts` it works? Perhaps try to: Use the `-p` option in snakemake to print shell commands and check for something odd; try running the command on the front node and check for queues in error. (Personally, I don't see the point of using wrappers - they add a layer of abstraction making debugging more difficult just to execute a single shell command)

Comment: I totally agree with you about the wrappers. This I a premade large workflow and editing every wrapper would be to much work though :).
Yes, without the java options everything works. This rule just takes very long :). I will try the -p flag and come back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper code imports some utils from [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrapper-utils/blob/master/snakemake_wrapper_utils/java.py#L3). Specifically, if you set `mem_mb` in resources, it adds `-Xmx{mem_mb}M` to your java invocation.  If you also specify `-Xmx` in `java_opts`, the code will exit with a message about having both mem_mb and -Xmx.  Not sure why you don't see that in the log, but that is why your job is failing.

You can, however, specify `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8` alone and it should work, taking the memory from your resources.

So, if you specify `mem_mb` or `mem_gb` in resources, do not include `-Xmx` in your `java_opts`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. That's strange since -Xmx4G is shown as an example for possible java_opts here: https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/0.74.0/wrappers/gatk/variantrecalibrator.html.
So, if I add `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8` do I have to set `threads: 8` too?

Comment: (+1) Troy, what's your opinion about wrappers? As I mentioned in my comment above, I'm skeptical about their utility since they make the pipeline more opaque - your answer seems to back up my objection. However, they seem quite popular and nextflow has a similar setup so I feel I'm missing something here...

Comment: @gernophil I suspect that the documentation lagged behind the version of the wrapper or it just doesn't specify the intricacies related to using resources.  There is no similar check for threads.  If you use the threads directive in your scheduler command you will want to also set ParallelGCThreads.  Consider using `{threads}` in the java_opts definition if possible.

Comment: @dariober I am on the fence with wrappers.  There are times when they can save you a lot of boilerplate and setting up exact versions of software, arguments, etc.  If you want to use a tool "out of the box" it is a nice feature to have.  In terms of documentation, the exact commands are hidden but it does provide simple version control. For new users, having to set up all the directives, conda environments, and debugging shell commands is a lot to ask.  Once you do anything beyond changing a few arguments, wrappers will not have enough flexibility,  So good for new people and simple cases.